# How to configure Sentry for work with Apache Solr

Tags: solr, mapr, apache-sentry

I downloaded the Apache Solr from github (https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr). Building the project using ANT and deploy .war file to TOMCAT7. Everything was successful. But now i want using Sentry for authorization in Apache Solr. I read a lot of documentation, but it not clarifying for me.

I don't understand how these two products have dependencies and how to start using the Sentry with Solr

Comment: "Sentry is a realtime event logging and aggregation platform. It specializes in monitoring errors and extracting all the information needed to do a proper post-mortem without any of the hassle of the standard user feedback loop." Are you sure Sentry is what you need to create auth features?

Comment: You are confusing between Apache Sentry and the event logging Sentry. The question is about Apache Sentry and Solr interaction, which is a very valid question.